# exifinterface Build error about androidX but i don't migrate to androidX

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

When i try to build app it give me this error on Build tab

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface.version

**And I don't use AndroidX in any of my modules**

I also add this to my `build.gradle`

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
```

`dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"

}
```

Comment: `Build error when migrate to androidX` You didn't. You still use the old support library dependencies. Start by going to menu Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX. After you're done come back here and update your question if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must add this line to my `packagingOptions`

```
exclude 'META-INF/androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface.version'
```

So my `packagingOptions` Change like this

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface.version'
}
```

Comment: I'm using exif interface in my project and didn't have to exclude anything. Solve your problem instead of hiding it. It means exif interface is bundled in your app multiple times, perhaps once from AndroidX and once from the old support library. I'm not sure. You can analyze your APK.

Answer (score 0):

But you didn't change your gradles to Android X library. Just migrate whole project to Android X.

Comment: `Just migrate whole project to Android X.` Avoid words `just` and `simply`. If everything was so simple this site wouldn't exist. Explain how to do it. Provide example how it would look at the end.

Comment: @TakeInfo, you write i'm not use androidX at all ! but why gives me AndroidX error i don't know

Comment: then check your gradle.properties file if there is "android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true" this two flags exist or not.